# Matplotlib/Basemap plotting wind barbs at equal distances apart

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot wind barbs, which are spaced 100km by 100km from each other. The data I have is for the northern hemisphere (0.25 degree). I tried to reproduce the problem in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

lons,lats = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-180,180,1440),np.linspace(0,90,360))


m = Basemap(projection='merc',resolution='l',llcrnrlat=33,llcrnrlon=-50,urcrnrlat=68,urcrnrlon=40)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.6)
X, Y = m(lons,lats)

UWind = np.ones((360,1440))
VWind = np.zeros((360,1440))

xx = np.arange(0, X.shape[1], 8)

yy = np.sin(np.deg2rad(np.linspace(0,90,45)))
yy = yy*360
yy[-1] = 359
yy = yy.astype(int)

points = np.meshgrid(yy, xx)

m.barbs(X[points], Y[points], UWind[points], VWind[points],length=4,linewidth=0.6,pivot='middle')


plt.show()
```

xx is chosen to plot a barb every 2 degrees (8 boxes at 0.25 degrees resolution). Of course, in this projection, latitude spacing will increase as latitude increases. So, to avoid this, I created yy which varies with sin (to counteract this). It doesn't seem to do anything. Any help is very welcome. The current plot this produces which isn't equal spacing (from a distance, not degrees, perspective).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the m.barbs and add a new line above which does the transform:

```
uproj,vproj,xx,yy = m.transform_vector(UWind,VWind,np.linspace(-180,180,1440),np.linspace(0,90,360),31,31,returnxy=True,masked=True)
m.barbs(xx,yy,uproj,vproj,length=4,linewidth=0.6,pivot='middle')
```

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html[image]

More Information here: https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.basemap